# Amazon Ec2 Slow Spin Up

Tags: web-applications, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to use Amazon EC2 for a web site and noticed extremely slow spin up times. The first request to a server that has not been in use for awhile (couple minutes) can take 5 or so minutes to display a simple web page.  After that first request the server responds very quickly. Is there a way to host a web application on EC2 and avoid these spin up times? Do reserved instances fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon EC2 instances don't have a "spin-up" time. The culprit is likely your code or your server setup, not EC2. Reserved instances aren't any different than any other type of instance other than the payment details.

Comment: There was something wrong with my code that was causing the major lag (Nothing worth stating here). Can you say for sure that there are no penalties for the first request to a vm that hasn't been accessed in a while? I'm not trying to argue that you are wrong but maybe providing a link or two would be more helpful than just denouncing my question.

Comment: Your question wasn't denounced, it was answered. VMs (which is what EC2 instances are) that haven't been accessed in a while have still been sitting there chugging away just like a physical server would.